# Implement early stopping in tf.estimator.DNNRegressor using the available training hooks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and want to implement early stopping in `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` with  available training hooks[Training Hooks](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Training_Hooks) for the MNIST dataset. The early stopping hook will stop training if the loss does not improve for some specified number of steps. Tensorflow documentaton only provides example for [Logging hooks](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#set_up_a_logging_hook). Can someone write a code snippet for implementing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a `EarlyStoppingHook` sample implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import logging
from tensorflow.python.training import session_run_hook


class EarlyStoppingHook(session_run_hook.SessionRunHook):
    """Hook that requests stop at a specified step."""

    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=0,
                 mode='auto'):
        """
        """
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.patience = patience
        self.min_delta = min_delta
        self.wait = 0
        if mode not in ['auto', 'min', 'max']:
            logging.warning('EarlyStopping mode %s is unknown, '
                            'fallback to auto mode.', mode, RuntimeWarning)
            mode = 'auto'

        if mode == 'min':
            self.monitor_op = np.less
        elif mode == 'max':
            self.monitor_op = np.greater
        else:
            if 'acc' in self.monitor:
                self.monitor_op = np.greater
            else:
                self.monitor_op = np.less

        if self.monitor_op == np.greater:
            self.min_delta *= 1
        else:
            self.min_delta *= -1

        self.best = np.Inf if self.monitor_op == np.less else -np.Inf

    def begin(self):
        # Convert names to tensors if given
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        self.monitor = graph.as_graph_element(self.monitor)
        if isinstance(self.monitor, tf.Operation):
            self.monitor = self.monitor.outputs[0]

    def before_run(self, run_context):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        return session_run_hook.SessionRunArgs(self.monitor)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        current = run_values.results

        if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                run_context.request_stop()
```

This implementation is based on [Keras implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/callbacks.py).

To use it with CNN MNIST [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) create hook and pass it to `train`.

```py
early_stopping_hook = EarlyStoppingHook(monitor='sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/value', patience=10)

mnist_classifier.train(
  input_fn=train_input_fn,
  steps=20000,
  hooks=[logging_hook, early_stopping_hook])
```

Here `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/value` is the name of the loss op in that example.

**EDIT 1:**

It looks like there is no "official" way of finding loss node when using estimators (or I can't find it).

For the `DNNRegressor` this node has name `dnn/head/weighted_loss/Sum`.

Here is how to find it in the graph:

1. Start tensorboard in model directory. In my case I didn't set any directory so estimator used temporary directory and printed this line:
   `WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpInj8SC`
   Start tensorboard:

   ```
   tensorboard --logdir /tmp/tmpInj8SC
   ```
2. Open it in browser and navigate to GRAPHS tab.
   [image]
3. Find loss in the graph. Expand blocks in the sequence: `dnn` → `head` → `weighted_loss` and click on the `Sum` node (note that there is summary node named `loss` connected to it).
   [image]
4. Name shown in the info "window" to the right is the name of the selected node, that need to be passed to `monitor` argument pf `EarlyStoppingHook`.

Loss node of the `DNNClassifier` has the same name by default. Both `DNNClassifier` and `DNNRegressor` have optional argument `loss_reduction` that influences loss node name and behavior (defaults to `losses.Reduction.SUM`).

**EDIT 2:**

There is a way of finding loss without looking at the graph.
You can use `GraphKeys.LOSSES` collection to get the loss. But this way will work only after training started. So you can use it only in a hook.

For example you can remove `monitor` argument from the `EarlyStoppingHook` class and change its `begin` function to always use the first loss in the collection:

```py
self.monitor = tf.get_default_graph().get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)[0]
```

You also probably need to check that there is a loss in the collection.

Comment: I want to use EarlyStoppingHook with tf.estimator.DNNRegressor and tf.estimator.DNNClassifier. I believe I need to pass some monitor arg . what that will be?

Comment: @abhishekjha, I updated answer to include this information

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But how do I save the weights in a particular step and retrieve it after the solution does not improve some specified number of steps?

Comment: @abhishekjha, it sound like a different question. You have many possibilities here: you can add this functionality to the hook implementation (for example using standard TF savers or storing weights in memory), or you can use existing `CheckpointSaverHook`. It depends on your particular needs.

Comment: great answer but I don't get why this is useful if you can't make your early stop condition based on the loss or accuracy on the validation set rather than the training set.

Comment: @dm0_ I thought the concept of early stopping was to compare the training and validation loss. When validation loss starts increasing, then you proceed to early stopping. However, in your example I can't find where validation gets involved. Could you explain please?

Comment: @TasosGlrs, early stopping is just a generic concept. It is about stopping your training before a condition defined at training start time reached. You can compare training and validation loss, or you can wait until validation loss stops decreasing as in this sample (borrowed from Keras).

Comment: @dm0_ okay sure, but I don't get how you involve the loss of the validation step. For example in a custom model I have, I do `estimator.train(...)` and `estimator.evaluate(...)`, but in the graph both have the same name `loss/mul:0`. How do you know if the one you monitor is the training or the evaluation loss?