# DNNClassifier's loss with EarlyStopping

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use a hook in my `DNNClassifier` model using [`tensorflow.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) but I have no idea what to put in `monitor`. The documentation is not exactly helpful here.

From looking at the code a softmax cross-entropy is used as the loss function but for `DNNRegressor` the loss node is `dnn/head/weighted_loss/Sum` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815906/implement-early-stopping-in-tf-estimator-dnnregressor-using-the-available-traini). I have tried getting Tensorboard up and running but I am not able to and the [import script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) from a saved model is equally defective on my machine.

Is there any way to figure out what the node of the `DNNClassifier`'s loss is?

Answer (score 1):

The `monitor` does not refer to a graph node or a layer, but to a loss or metric value. Indeed any value can be used that is present in your `logs` dictionary: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L676

You can inspect the values you have in `logs` without debugging, by using `CSVLogger` for instance:

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger(filename=os.path.join(args.log_dir, 'train.csv'), separator=',', append=False)
```

If you cannot write to a file, you can print out everything you have in `logs` to stdout:

```
mycallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: print('\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in logs.items()])))
```

In case you do not have the metric in `logs`, you can use LambdaCallback to put it there. For instance:

```
eval_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: logs.update({'metric_name': get_metric_value()}))

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='metric_name', min_delta=0.0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='min')
```

Comment: I'm running the code inside a Jupyter notebook and getting to the logs is troublesome. Is there also a way to read it from the graph.pbtxt?

Comment: Can I add that to the hooks in `DNNClassifier`? If I do so, I get ''LambdaCallback' object is not iterable'

Comment: Currently it is impossible to use Keras callbacks with TF estimators. Feature request: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21979

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I tried (and failed at) it. It also seems that `stop_if_no_increase_hook` does not yet work in distributed mode, even with `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`.